# GestureDetector - method onDown but in left

Tags: java, android

I have method which show Toast with text.
I Call this method in method `onDown()` from `GetureDetector`

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //here i have method for this toast
    return false;
}
```

Now when we touch screen, we can saw this text from Toast.

Now i want to do something like this, but only when we'll touch and slide your finger to the left. I can not find such a method in doc.
 How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect swipe event, you need to override `SimpleOnGestureListener#onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` method. Here is an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector detector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_tester);
        detector = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeListener());
    }     

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        boolean consumed = detector.onTouchEvent(e);
        if (consumed) {return true;} 
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    public class SwipeListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
         public static final int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 40; 

        /**
         * Whether or not you use {@link GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener},
         * you must always implement an {@link OnGestureListener#onDown(MotionEvent)}
         * method that returns {@code true}. This step is necessary because all gestures
         * begin with an {@code onDown()} message.
         *
         * For more details see
         * https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/making-interactive.html#inputgesture
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * @return {@code true} if event is consumed by this method.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
           float xDiff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
           float yDiff = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
           return resolveSwipe(xDiff, yDiff);
        }

        /**
         * @return {@code true} if swipe movement was detected.
         */
        private boolean resolveSwipe(float xDist, float yDist) {
            float yDistAbs = Math.abs(yDist);
            float xDistAbs = Math.abs(xDist);

            SwipeDirection swipeDirection;

            // movement along y axis is dominant = resolve as vertical movement
            if (yDistAbs > xDistAbs) {
                if (yDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
                swipeDirection = (yDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.DOWN: SwipeDirection.UP;

            } else {
                if (xDistAbs < MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE) {return false;}
                swipeDirection = (xDist > 0) ? SwipeDirection.RIGHT: SwipeDirection.LEFT;
            }

            onSwipeEvent(swipeDirection);
            return true;
        }

        private void onSwipeEvent(SwipeDirection swipeDirection) {
            if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.UP) {
                Log.d("[MATONI]", "[CLASS]: " + SwipeListener.class.getSimpleName() + ", [MESSAGE]: UP");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "UP",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.DOWN) {
                Log.d("[MATONI]", "[CLASS]: " + SwipeListener.class.getSimpleName() + ", [MESSAGE]: DOWN");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "DOWN",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.LEFT) {
                Log.d("[MATONI]", "[CLASS]: " + SwipeListener.class.getSimpleName() + ", [MESSAGE]: LEFT");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "LEFT",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.RIGHT) {
                Log.d("[MATONI]", "[CLASS]: " + SwipeListener.class.getSimpleName() + ", [MESSAGE]: RIGHT");
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "RIGHT",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            // or alternatively
            //switch (swipeDirection) {
            //    case UP: Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //        break;
            //    case DOWN: Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //        break;
            //    case LEFT: Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //        break;
            //    case RIGHT: Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //        break;
            //    default: new AssertionError("Should not happen");
            //}
        }
    }

    public enum SwipeDirection {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }
}
```

For more details about `GestureDetector` see [Detecting Common Gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html).

Comment: so now i need to make in method onSwipeEvent, if swipeDirection.RIGHT use Toast ?

Comment: @jackfield exactly, make sure class SwipeListener  is contained within activity so you can access activity's context which is required by toast

Comment: when i do if(swipeDirection.RIGHT) {} AndroidStudio underline "swipeDirection" and say "Required boolean and found SwipeDirection"

Comment: swipeDirection is enum, while if statement requires boolean expression, so you need to write `if (swipeDirection == SwipeDirection.RIGHT) {/*do-something*/}`

Comment: something is wrong, when i move in RIGHT it is good, but when i move LEFT, method is call 2x time

Comment: @jackfield do you detect somewhere else swipe movement? e. g. in `onTouch` method like decribed by @Anmol?

Comment: @jackfield tested, did not spot anything wrong. maybe your code flow is wrong in `onSwipeEvent()` method, I will edit my answer so you can compare it with your implementation.

Comment: why you using "return" after every if ? without return is also that same

Comment: it will ensure, that method is terminated after `if`, so it would not be executed some code which is not contained in if-statements. In my case, there is no code, so you can ommit these return statements.

Comment: ok, it work, but last question, What is the distance (MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 40; 
) for ? it is not difference when i change to 1 or 1000

Comment: @jackfield it is a required distance in pixels to translate finger move as swipe event, you can change it to any value you want. If this solution helped you consider to mark the answer as accpted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by check the coOrdiantes in motionEvent

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = 0;
        switch (event.getAction()){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                Log.e("x",x+"");
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.e("newX",event.getX()+"");
                if (event.getX() < (x-20)){
                    // toast here
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: androidStudio underline getX "Non-static method getx() cannot be reference from a static contex"

Comment: can you post your code over here, because you must be making some mistake. It always work just fine for me

Comment: "y" is never used, so why we need y ? There is too much code, I can not send

Comment: yea y can be deleted as it was used in my project from which i gave you the code. and are you calling this in any static method and make sure you are calling getX() with the MotionEvent object which is parameter in onDown method

Comment: ok, i repaired this static error, now work, but app no show this toast when i touch to left

Comment: try to use it in `onTouch` rather than in `Gesture Detector`

Comment: i can use only Gesture Detector ;/

Comment: it worked for me in onTouch i think it will work in Gesture detector as well, as it gices the MotionEvent, can you please tell me the values of the Logs, x and newX ??